# Unable to write to NFS share, Finder hanging

Tags: linux, nfs, mac, terminal, finder

I've a issue with an nfs share : this is my setup :

/etc/exports :

```
/home/delaland/sharetest 111.111.111.111(rw,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=100,sync,insecure,no_subtree_check)
```

all needed ports open
Mounting on my mac with these commands :

```
mkdir -m 777 /Volumes/sharetest
mount -t nfs -o rw,soft,intr,rsize=16384,wsize=16384,timeo=900,retrans=3,proto=tcp limesky.net:/home/someuser/sharetest /Volumes/sharetest
```

I create a mount point with mode 777 to be able to write on it, when I mount on a normal folder, Finder does not let me write to or modify.

By doing so, I'm able to modify file and folder names on the nfs share, so I assume I have write rights.
mounting and reading goes fast and is very responsive.

But when I try to write a file, Transfer dialog stays forever on 'calculating remaining time'.. I then need to force quit Mac Finder and restart it.

Then, When I try to remount the NFS, it has no access..: it just loads the folder content forever.

The only way to get it back to normal is to delete the 0 and 4 bytes files on the nfs share server side..:

```
0   testfile.txt
4   ._testfile.txt
```

For example: when I upload testfile.txt (1kb)

Finder tries for a minute, the says server is disconnected.
inside /var/log/messages I find this :

```
Jan 16 20:08:37 sv kernel: lockd: cannot monitor Mac-Pro-de-Vincent.local
```

or this :

```
Jan 16 19:55:55 whm kernel: lockd: server Mac-Pro-de-Vincent.local not responding, timed out
```

What Am I doing wrong any idea?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I am seeing a very similar issue with a Docker-ized NFSv4 server on my Raspberry Pi (Debian-based Raspbian) and my Mac on 10.13.6 High Sierra: Mounting a share from the terminal and writing to it works fine. When mounting the share with Finder (CMD+K), I am able to read and create directories on the share, but get an infinite "calculating remaining time" when trying to copy a file. On the server, I also get the testfile.txt and ._testfile.txt artifacts, also 0 and 4 kB in size. /var/log/messages does however not give any cues about lockd or similar

Answer (score 0):

You have to change to 777 directory on the server. The mount point mode makes no sense as permissions will be checked against directory on the server. The better way is to change directory ownership to uid which will be used on the server (100?).